# Disable a particular span using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a calendar event app where you can save people's birthday dates and edit people's names or dates whenever you want.

To display stored events I am using a `forEach` loop in JSP. I have a span named `ld-option-okay-edit` in each div. You can edit previous data after you click on that span and save your data.

But before clicking on the save button I am checking whether any field in a particular div is empty or not, using a jQuery hover function.

If any field is empty then I am disabling the span element so that it can't forward request to the servlet, but the problem is I am not able to disable it.
??????
THE PROBLEM
???????
 My question is how can I disable a span through jQuery, or how can I prevent the onclick event of a span using jQuery?

Here is my code:

```
<c:forEach items="${relativeUser}" var="user"> 
    <div class="elementsdiv">
        <form action="<c:url value=" ******">" method="post"> 
           <div class="cld-option-okay"  >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok cld-option-okay-edit" name="cld-option-okay-edit" ></span>                                   
            </div>  
                <div class="cld-option-name" >
                <input class="cld-name-input" value="${user.name}" placeholder="Name of the person" type="text" name="name">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

What I have tried until now in jQuery is:

```
$(".elementsdiv").each(function (i, data) {
    $($(data).find('.cld-option-okay')).hover(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($($(data).find('input[name="name"]')).val() === "") {                      
            $($(data).find('span[name="cld-option-okay-edit"]')).addClass('disabled');//in this line  i am getting trouble 
        }
    }
});
```

For that line I even tried:

```
1)$($(data).find('span[name="cld-option-okay-edit"]')).attr("disabled","true");//with single quote also
2)$($(data).find('span[name="cld-option-okay-edit"]')).attr("disabled","disabled");//with single quote also
3).prop("disabled", true );
4).attr('disabled', '');
5).attr("disabled", "disabled");
6).off( "click", "**" );
7).unbind( "click", handler );

but when I apply:    
    `$($(data).find('span[name="cld-option-okay-edit"]')).hide()`;//it is applying   
**********************
       `$($(data).find('span[name="cld-option-okay-edit"]'))`till here code is working fine my problem is in applying disable.
previously i applied disable like below    

    $('.cld-option-okay-edit').addClass('disabled');

but it disables  okay span in all divs
*************************
```

Comment: You should never have to do `$($(XXXX))`! find returns a jQuery object, there is no need to wrap it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For enable or disable a span, you could do it like this:

```
var isEmpty = false;

$('#myDiv > input').keyup(function(){ 
    isEmpty = false;

    $('#myDiv > input').each(function(i,obj){
        if(this.value == ""){
            isEmpty = true;

            return false;
        } 
    });

    // Styles for the span.
    if( ! isEmpty){
        $('#myDiv > span').removeClass('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#myDiv > span').addClass('disabled');
    }
});

$('#myDiv > span').click(function(){
    if(isEmpty){
        alert("disabled");
    } else {
        alert("enabled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your code should look like based on what you have written, but I am not sure it is actually what you want to happen. If you want to disable it, you need to use prop()

```
$(".elementsdiv").each(function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    elem.find('.cld-option-okay').hover(function(e) {
        if (elem.find('input[name="name"]').val() === "") {
            elem.find('span[name="cld-option-okay-edit"]').addClass('disabled'); /*.prop("disabled",true); */
        }
    });
});
```